# How to select previous month in mysql with variable?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$m=01
$y=2016
```

Given a month, how to find the value of the previous month? (In this example: December 2015)

Comment: "last month" or "previous month" ?

Comment: last month and not used CURRENT_DATE , using  custom variables.

Comment: No example of custom variables ?

Comment: yeps, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

```
select CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(d,-(day(getdate())),getdate()),106)
```

Comment: This looks like Microsoft T-SQL syntax, i.e. SQL Server not MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INTERVAL 1 MONTH` in order to fetch the previous month:

```
SELECT MONTH(A._DATE) as _MONTH, YEAR(A._DATE) as _YEAR from (
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('01/2016', '%m/%Y'),'%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
 as _DATE
FROM DUAL) A
                                  ^
                         custom-variable in string format
```

**OUTPUT**

```
_MONTH  _YEAR
12      2015
```

See [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/3589)

Answer (score 0):

The `$` (dollar sign) character isn't a variable identifier in MySQL. User defined variables start with an `@` (at sign) character.

```
SET @m = '01';
SET @y = '2016';
```

To do some date calculations, you can convert the contents of those variables into a date.  For example, concatenate them together

```
 SELECT CONCAT(@y,'-',@m,'-01')
```

That gives you a string `'2016-01-01'` that can be implicitly converted into a date. To subtract a month:

```
 SELECT CONCAT(@y,'-',@m,'-01') + INTERVAL -1 MONTH
```

That gives you a date value of the first of the prior month.  To return the string `'December 2015'` from that, you can use the `DATE_FORMAT` function with appropriate format specifiers.  `%M` gets you the month name spelled out, and `%Y` gets you a four digit year.

```
 SELECT @m := '01' AS m, @y := '2016' AS y ; 
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(@y,'-',@m,'-01') + INTERVAL -1 MONTH,'%M %Y') AS prior_month
```

(It's not a requirement to use user-defined variables; but the question seemed to be asking about variables. If those values are coming from a host language, you could use a prepared statement with bind placeholders:

Either named bind placeholders:

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT( :y ,'-', :m ,'-01') + INTERVAL -1 MONTH,'%M %Y') AS prior_month
```

Or positional:

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT( ? ,'-', ? ,'-01') + INTERVAL -1 MONTH,'%M %Y') AS prior_month
```

Or, less preferred, just supply literals in the SQL text

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT('2016','-','01','-01') + INTERVAL -1 MONTH,'%M %Y')
```